# Group cohomology $G$-module $M$, with $M$ non-abelian?

Tags: algebraic-topology, modules, group-cohomology

Is the group cohomology $H^d(G,M)$ $G$-module $M$, the $M$ can be non-abelian?

Or can $M$ be abelian?

If $M$ cannot be non-abelian, what is the reason?

Comment: If $d = 0$ or $d=1$, this can be done. But if $d \geq 2$, apparently there is no non-abelian group cohomology…

Comment: @ watson, thanks - I heard/knew the statement, but why not?

Comment: Some relevant links : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2390/why-does-non-abelian-group-cohomology-exist (see the comment « And the reason, in turn, that K(A,1) exists for nonabelian groups but not K(A,n) for higher n is the Eckmann-Hilton argument showing that pi_n is abelian for n>1 »), https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nonabelian+group+cohomology (see « However, if the group $K$ is not abelian, then its n-fold delooping does not exist for $n \geq 2$ »).

Comment: In the book advertised at http://groupoids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html there is a Chapter 12: "Nonabelian cohomology: spaces, groupoids" which deals with coefficients in a crossed module. This is relevant to extension theory. Background developed is the use of _free crossed resolutions_, instead of  chain complexes.